# request btc payment when insufficient btc sent

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, bip70-payment-protocol

If a transaction was made and not enough btc to cover it, what are the options to add to the btc to cover the transaction.  How does the request payment work in this instance?

Comment: A transaction implicitly includes a transaction fee that pays to the miner. Are you talking about a transaction that does not have a high enough fee rate to get confirmed in the blockchain? Or something else?

Comment: *(from sender's perspective)* see [Replace-By-Fee (RBF) - BIP-125](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0125.mediawiki). **Samourai Wallet** supports it.